# Creating Batch to keeping one file and deleting the rest when all files have same extension and in same folder

Tags: batch-file

I need to create a `batch command` that will keep one file from all the same extensions and delete the rest of them.

`For example`, I have folder called `Photograph on desktop`.  It contains pictures that are all in `.png` format.  However, out of those files I want to keep `birds.png` and delete the rest of pictures.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Very easy. Use the `for /r` loop

```
for /r "Photograph" %%a in (*) do (
if %%~na NEQ [file to keep e.g. bird] del "%%a"
)
```

Run this from the desktop and it will delete all files put in the folder "Photograph" except for the file name put in the specified place.

I tried this myself and it worked fine. Tell me if you need anything else,

Yours Mona

### Alternate

```
forfiles /p "[pathtofile including file itself]" /c "cme.exe /c if @fname NEQ "bird" del @path"
```

That should work.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Mona.  I have one more question.  What if I want to place this bat file somewhere other than desktop?  should I add full folder location where it says "photograph"?

Comment: yea pretty much, replace `"Photograph"` with `"C:\pathtofile"`, also if you found this useful don't forget to make this answer correct. Yours Mona

Comment: Sorry for asking lot of questions. I tried your code and also tried one with adding full path to folder, it didn't seem to delete any files. I added this code and saved as test.bat and double clicked it. But nothing happened.

Comment: The alternate should do it

Comment: please type up what you are exactly doing

Comment: i have @echo off on top then right below it, I have your code with path as "[C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\photogragh\bird.png]" saved it as test.bat

Comment: ahh.... that's why, get rid of the braces, it should be "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\photogragh\bird.png" the braces indicate to follow the instructions and replace the braces with whatever is valid.

Comment: I removed [ ] but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: what is the error message, check everything, because I tested the first command myself and it worked perfectly

Comment: I don't get any error msg. I get some window pop up and it goes away.  Looks like CMD window

Comment: I did that it says Error: the specified directory does not exist press any key to continue... weird, I really do have folder on desktop.  I don't know why it says location doesn't exist

Comment: Then the problem is beyond my help, try running it from the desktop or from the file it self. if the latter use this: `for /r %%a in (*.png) do (if %%~na NEQ "bird" del "%%a")`. That way, you can avoid  problem with the path.

Answer (score 1):

Don't run it in any other folder than the one you need it in. :)

```
@echo off
attrib +h bird.png
del *.png
attrib -h bird.png
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

if NOT EXIST %2 (
echo "Usage: allBut.bat <pattern> <filename>
goto:end
)

for %%f in (%1) do (
IF NOT %%f==%2 (
    echo Deleting %%f because it is not %2
    del %%f
)
)
```

e.g. allBut *.png bird.png